# Standard ML - Going through a tutorial but example fails

Tags: sml

I'm going through the tutorial here...

http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/course-notes/sml/tut2.htm

where it defines several things to be used as a function...

```
val first = hd o explode;
val second = hd o tl o explode;
val third = hd o tl o tl o explode;
val fourth = hd o tl o tl o tl o explode;
val last = hd o rev o explode;
```

Which then is used...

```
fun roll s = fourth s ^ first s ^ second s ^ third s;
```

It seems like it should work but when I try that, I get the following errors below.  Anyone know what might be going?

```
stdIn:159.14-159.53 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string * string
  operand:         char * char
  in expression:
    fourth s ^ first s

stdIn:159.14-159.53 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string * string
  operand:         _ * char
  in expression:
    fourth s ^ first s ^ second s

stdIn:159.14-159.53 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string * string
  operand:         _ * char
  in expression:
    fourth s ^ first s ^ second s ^ third s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation operator concatenates `string`s (it's type is `string * string -> string`), but the `first`, `second`, ... functions are of type `string -> char`. Obviously we're going to get a complaint from the compiler if we try to give `^` a `char * char` tuple.

The tutorial links to [this page](http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/course-notes/sml/mosml.htm) with a fix:

> Change the definitions given in question 6 to
>   `fun roll s = implode[fourth s,first s,second s,third s];`
>   `fun exch s = implode[second s,first s,third s,fourth s];`

I'd imagine their code works in *some* version of SML, but it doesn't work in SML/NJ for me, despite the fact their note is only for Moscow ML.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I wasn't sure if it had to do with the different versions of ML or something was wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the operator `^` works on strings like this:

`"ab" ^ "cd" == "abcd"`

However, the functions `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth` and `last` all return chars.

The function `implode` from [the string standard library](http://sml-family.org/Basis/string.html) would help here.

Comment: Thank you ndujay!  It just seems odd to me that the tutorial lists the functions as such and has been around for a while - I thought it could be due to the ML version.  

Also, I get the error when I try to define the function as opposed to calling it.

Comment: See @william-z 's answer for more explanation.